# Extracting root with a microcontroller

Tags: c, extract

I saw a method for extracting root with a microcontroller in a book. I can't understand the process. Why does p=0x80 in the code below? In this case, if we have a small number, it will do many useless cycles, won't it?

```
unsigned int math_sqrt(unsigned int x)
{ 
  unsigned char ans = 0,p = 0x80;
  while(p!=0){
     ans+=p;
     if(ans*ans>x)
       ans-=p;
     p = (unsigned char)(p/2);
  }
  return ans;
}
```

I am new to microcontrollers and C. I'm sorry that maybe my English expression has some problems. By the way, can I use `math.h` in microcontoller like stm32 or K60? Thanks.

Comment: That code does at most 8 cycles of the loop.  Whether that's "many useless cycles" depend on your viewpoint.  The code won't work reliably unless `sizeof(unsigned int) == 2 * sizeof(unsigned char) && CHAR_BIT == 8`, but that could be valid in a micro-controller (basically, unless your `int` types are 16-bit, not 32-bit).

Comment: If the condition is satisfed, dose the code mean I try it from the high data to search for the answer but not like we usuallly from 1 to more? Can i understand this code like that?

Comment: Yes, the code tries to establish the more significant bits of the result before the less significant ones.

Comment: OK,I got it. What do you think of this way? Does it have any advantages?(I mean from more to less)

Comment: It’s probably quicker this way, on average, unless perhaps you normally seek the square root of small numbers.  Try any alternative you prefer and benchmark the two. This is likely to perform well.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler Thanks for your patient answer.I'm sorry for replying late. I can understand the work process with the code.But it seems that I can't find the advantage obviously.May be the numbers I used to test are small.What order of magnitude do you think the code can show its advantage? Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a math complement to Jonathan's nice answer.

The rationale beyond the algorithm, is that the square root of an `uint16_t` is a `uint8_t`, that means a number between 0 and 255. As the functions square and square root are both monotonic, you can use dichotomy to find the closest solution. You just have to start in the middle of the possible interval, that is 128 or 0x80. Then you iterate each time on an interval of half size which allows to be soon (8 stages max) to an *interval* of size 1: the solution.

Comment: Your answer explain the algorithm well and let me understand the code and the axiom more clearly~

Answer (score 0):

#### Accuracy of the code

> Maybe the numbers I used to test are small. What order of magnitude do you think the code can show its advantage?

It works correctly for inputs in the range 0..65535.

Here's some simple test code that you could run — well, could run if you had my `isqrt_32()` function, but it wouldn't be hard to chop that out and use just the standard C library `sqrt()` function.

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "isqrt.h"

static unsigned int math_sqrt(unsigned int x)
{ 
  unsigned char ans = 0,p = 0x80;
  while(p!=0){
     ans+=p;
     if(ans*ans>x)
       ans-=p;
     p = (unsigned char)(p/2);
  }
  return ans;
}

int main(void)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 70000; i++)
    {
        int v1 = isqrt_32(i);
        int v2 = math_sqrt(i);
        double d1 = sqrt(i);
        int v3 = d1;
        if (v1 != v2 || v1 != v3)
            printf("%5d: %5d vs %5d vs %5d (%9.6f)\n", i, v1, v2, v3, d1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The signature of `isqrt_32()` is: `extern int32_t isqrt_32(uint32_t x);`

When run, the output starts:

```
65536:   256 vs   255 vs   256 (256.000000)
65537:   256 vs   255 vs   256 (256.001953)
65538:   256 vs   255 vs   256 (256.003906)
65539:   256 vs   255 vs   256 (256.005859)
65540:   256 vs   255 vs   256 (256.007812)
65541:   256 vs   255 vs   256 (256.009765)
65542:   256 vs   255 vs   256 (256.011718)
65543:   256 vs   255 vs   256 (256.013672)
65544:   256 vs   255 vs   256 (256.015625)
65545:   256 vs   255 vs   256 (256.017578)
```

The code shown in the question is about as quick as it gets for 16-bit unsigned integer square roots if the spectrum of inputs is not constrained further than by being a 16-bit unsigned integer.

#### What is in `isqrt_32()`

I went and looked at the code behind `isqrt_32()` and had a reminder of times past.  The code I use is based on some public domain code posted in the comp.lang.c news group by Chris Torek not later than 1991 (I picked up a reposted copy from 1991-08-14).

The key sample timing results are (2011-11-27 on MacOS X 10.7.2 on a 2.3 GHz Intel Core i7 with 8 GB 1333 MHz DDR3 memory):

```
CT 0.482771 (1370731968); JL 2.074758 (1370731968); MT 0.125003 (1507082656)
CT 0.404681 (1370731968); JL 1.825984 (1370731968); MT 0.086421 (1507082656)
CT 0.509388 (1370731968); JL 1.900582 (1370731968); MT 0.094746 (1507082656)
CT 0.534594 (1370731968); JL 1.866929 (1370731968); MT 0.095474 (1507082656)
CT 0.447996 (1370731968); JL 2.211031 (1370731968); MT 0.120391 (1507082656)
```

In 2017, I tested with an updated version of the code that also tests:

```
int32_t isqrt_db(uint32_t x)
{
    return sqrt(x);
}
```

The results show that on my test platform, using the library function is noticeably faster than using the integer function (2017-12-23 on macOS 10.13.2 on a 2.7 GHz Intel Core i7 with 16 GiB 2133 Mhz LPDDR3 memory):

```
CT 0.217224 (1370731968); JL 1.479817 (1370731968); DB 0.125086 (1370731968); MT 0.086683 (1507082656)
CT 0.211790 (1370731968); JL 1.478602 (1370731968); DB 0.129983 (1370731968); MT 0.085262 (1507082656)
CT 0.213528 (1370731968); JL 1.478100 (1370731968); DB 0.124773 (1370731968); MT 0.082611 (1507082656)
CT 0.212352 (1370731968); JL 1.494118 (1370731968); DB 0.130582 (1370731968); MT 0.085290 (1507082656)
CT 0.211442 (1370731968); JL 1.499416 (1370731968); DB 0.127462 (1370731968); MT 0.082682 (1507082656)
```

In 2011, the Chris Torek (CT) times were about 1/4 (to 1/5) of the JL times.  In 2017, the disparity was greater, nearer 1/7.  However, in 2017, the system library `sqrt()` was almost twice as fast as the CT code.

The MT times are for an empty (em-tee) square root function that simply returns its input.  It's a measure of function call overhead — it isn't significant, or readily avoidable.

However, that is a machine with hardware floating point (the chip has a floating point square root instruction).  If the microcontroller does not have a floating point unit, or if the floating point unit does not have the square root instruction, you are likely to find that the integer software version is (noticeably — probably very noticeably) faster than the floating point code.

JFTR: The compilation in 2017 was:

```
gcc -m64 -I/Users/jleffler/inc -I. -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DJLSS_STDERR -O3 -fPIC -g -std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wshadow -Wmissing-prototypes -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wold-style-definition -Wcast-qual -Wstrict-prototypes -c isqrt.c
```

That's extremely fussy, but the key point is the `-O3` optimization; this was optimized code.  The test code prints the accumulated sums in part as a consistency check, and in part to ensure that the optimizer doesn't eliminate code by spotting that the same thing is being done 10,000 times.  That said, the pointer-to-function in the test code also cuts down on the opportunities for super-extreme abuse by the optimizer.  Versions of the code prior to 2017-12-23 did not use the pointer to function testing and were more vulnerable to extreme optimization.

Most of this code is available on GitHub in my [SOQ](https://github.com/jleffler/soq) (Stack Overflow Questions) repository as files in the
[src/libsoq](https://github.com/jleffler/soq/tree/master/src/libsoq) sub-directory.  The file `isqrt32.c` is based on an older version of the code
shown below; the file `isqrt64.c` is somewhat similar.  I need to do some updating.

#### TL;DR — Benchmark when performance matters

- This demonstrates yet again the importance of benchmarking for the machines where it matters when performance matters.

<sup>*The licence for this code is [CC-by-SA 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) with [attribution required](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/25/attribution-required/), as with the rest of SO — see the bottom of any page on SO.*</sup>

```
/*
@(#)File:           $RCSfile: isqrt.c,v $
@(#)Version:        $Revision: 1.14 $
@(#)Last changed:   $Date: 2017/12/23 17:12:52 $
@(#)Purpose:        Integer square root calculation
@(#)Author:         J Leffler
@(#)Copyright:      (C) JLSS 1991-2017
*/

/*TABSTOP=4*/

#ifndef lint
/* Prevent over-aggressive optimizers from eliminating ID string */
extern const char jlss_id_isqrt_c[];
const char jlss_id_isqrt_c[] = "@(#)$Id: isqrt.c,v 1.14 2017/12/23 17:12:52 jleffler Exp $";
#endif /* lint */

/* Configuration: use public domain implementation unless -DUSE_JLSS_ISQRT */
#undef USE_PUBLIC_DOMAIN
#ifndef USE_JLSS_ISQRT
#define USE_PUBLIC_DOMAIN
#endif /* USE_JLSS_ISQRT */

#include "isqrt.h"

#if defined(USE_TIMING_TESTS)
extern int32_t isqrt_jl(uint32_t x);
extern int32_t isqrt_ct(uint32_t x);
#else
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wunused-macros"
#define isqrt_jl(x) isqrt_32(x)
#define isqrt_ct(x) isqrt_32(x)
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
#endif /* USE_TIMING_TESTS */

#if !defined(USE_PUBLIC_DOMAIN) || defined(USE_TIMING_TESTS)
/*
** Algorithm by J Leffler: slow but correct
*/
int32_t isqrt_jl(uint32_t x)
{
    uint32_t x1;
    uint32_t x2;

    /* Special cases:              */
    /* x == 0 => return 0 CORRECT */
    /* x <  4 => return 1 CORRECT */
    if (x < 4)
        return(x > 0);

    x1 = x / 4;
    while ((x2 = ((x / x1 + x1) / 2)) != x1)
    {
        if (x2 == x1 + 1 && x2 > x / x2 && x1 < x / x1)
            return(x1);
        x1 = x2;
    }
    return(x1);
}
#endif /* !USE_PUBLIC_DOMAIN || USE_TIMING_TESTS */

#if defined(USE_PUBLIC_DOMAIN) || defined(USE_TIMING_TESTS)
/*
** Code by Chris Torek: fast and correct
*/
/*
** From: edelsohn@sccs.syr.edu (David Edelsohn)
** Subject: Re: quick sqrt()
** Message-ID: <1991Aug14.161849.18548@rodan.acs.syr.edu>
** Date: 14 Aug 91 20:18:49 GMT
** Organization: Syracuse Center for Computational Science/Dept of Physics
**
** I tried replying to the poster but my email bounced and Chris Torek
** has not jumped in with his previous solution, so I will repost it for him:
** >From: chris@mimsy.umd.edu (Chris Torek)
** >Subject: Re: Integer Square Root (Was Re: # to the nth power)
**
** Integer square root routine, good for up to 32-bit values.
** Note that the largest square root (that of 0xffffffff)is
** 0xffff, so the result fits in a regular unsigned and need
** not be `long'.
**
** Original code from Tomas Rokicki (using a well known algorithm).
** This version by Chris Torek, University of Maryland.
**
** This code is in the public domain.
*/
int32_t isqrt_ct(uint32_t v)
{
    uint32_t t = 1L << 30;
    uint32_t r = 0;
    uint32_t s;

#undef STEP
#define STEP(k) \
    s = t + r; \
    r >>= 1; \
    if (s <= v) { \
        v -= s; \
        r |= t; \
    }

    STEP(15);
    t >>= 2;
    STEP(14);
    t >>= 2;
    STEP(13);
    t >>= 2;
    STEP(12);
    t >>= 2;
    STEP(11);
    t >>= 2;
    STEP(10);
    t >>= 2;
    STEP(9);
    t >>= 2;
    STEP(8);
    t >>= 2;
    STEP(7);
    t >>= 2;
    STEP(6);
    t >>= 2;
    STEP(5);
    t >>= 2;
    STEP(4);
    t >>= 2;
    STEP(3);
    t >>= 2;
    STEP(2);
    t >>= 2;
    STEP(1);
    t >>= 2;
    STEP(0);
    return (int32_t)r;
}
#endif /* USE_PUBLIC_DOMAIN || USE_TIMING_TESTS */

#if defined(TEST)
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

#if defined(USE_TIMING_TESTS)
/*
** Representative timings - (2011-11-27 on MacOS X 10.7.2 on a 2.3 GHz Intel Core i7
** with 8 GB 1333 MHz DDR3 memory).
**
** CT 0.482771 (1370731968); JL 2.074758 (1370731968); MT 0.125003 (1507082656)
** CT 0.404681 (1370731968); JL 1.825984 (1370731968); MT 0.086421 (1507082656)
** CT 0.509388 (1370731968); JL 1.900582 (1370731968); MT 0.094746 (1507082656)
** CT 0.534594 (1370731968); JL 1.866929 (1370731968); MT 0.095474 (1507082656)
** CT 0.447996 (1370731968); JL 2.211031 (1370731968); MT 0.120391 (1507082656)
**
** With the augmented test timing the conversion to double, use library
** square root, and convert back to integer too, the results (2017-12-23
** on macOS 10.13.2 on a 2.7 GHz Intel Core i7 with 16 GiB 2133 Mhz
** LPDDR3 memory) were:
**
** CT 0.217224 (1370731968); JL 1.479817 (1370731968); DB 0.125086 (1370731968); MT 0.086683 (1507082656)
** CT 0.211790 (1370731968); JL 1.478602 (1370731968); DB 0.129983 (1370731968); MT 0.085262 (1507082656)
** CT 0.213528 (1370731968); JL 1.478100 (1370731968); DB 0.124773 (1370731968); MT 0.082611 (1507082656)
** CT 0.212352 (1370731968); JL 1.494118 (1370731968); DB 0.130582 (1370731968); MT 0.085290 (1507082656)
** CT 0.211442 (1370731968); JL 1.499416 (1370731968); DB 0.127462 (1370731968); MT 0.082682 (1507082656)
**
** Note that on a machine with hardware floating point, the system
** library is close to twice as fast as the CT algorithm, which is about
** 7 times as fast as the JL algorithm.  If the CPU doesn't have
** hardware floating point, then the integer algorithms will be far
** faster than simulated floating point.  This does demonstrate the
** importance of benchmarking, though.
*/

#include "timer.h"

enum { ITERATIONS = 100000 };

static inline uint32_t next_x(uint32_t x)
{
    return (234ULL * x) / 213ULL + 1;
}

extern int32_t isqrt_mt(uint32_t x);
extern int32_t isqrt_db(uint32_t x);

/* Empty isqrt function - measure function call/return overhead */
int32_t isqrt_mt(uint32_t x)
{
    return x;
}

/* Double isqrt function - convert to double, use standard sqrt function, convert back */
int32_t isqrt_db(uint32_t x)
{
    /* Shorthand for: double d = x; d = sqrt(d); x = d; return x; */
    return sqrt(x);
}

typedef int32_t (*Sqrt_Fn)(uint32_t x);

typedef struct Time_Test
{
    Sqrt_Fn     fn;
    const char *prefix;
    const char *tag;
} Time_Test;

static const Time_Test tests[] =
{
    {   isqrt_ct,   "", "CT" },     /* Public domain (Chris Torek) algorithm */
    {   isqrt_jl, "; ", "JL" },     /* JLSS algorithm */
    {   isqrt_db, "; ", "DB" },     /* Double algorithm */
    {   isqrt_mt, "; ", "MT" },     /* Empty algorithm */
};
enum { NUM_TESTS = sizeof(tests) / sizeof(tests[0]) };

static void time_isqrt_function(Sqrt_Fn fn, Clock *clk, uint32_t *acc)
{
    clk_start(clk);
    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < ITERATIONS; i++)
    {
        for (uint32_t x = 0; x < UINT32_MAX / 2; x = next_x(x))
        {
            int32_t v = (*fn)(x);
            *acc += v + i;
        }
    }
    clk_stop(clk);
}

static void time_test(const Time_Test *test)
{
    Clock clk;
    uint32_t acc = 0;
    char buffer[32];
    time_isqrt_function(test->fn, &clk, &acc);
    printf("%s%s %8s (%" PRIu32 ")", test->prefix, test->tag,
           clk_elapsed_us(&clk, buffer, sizeof(buffer)), acc);
}

int main(void)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_TESTS; i++)
        time_test(&tests[i]);
    putchar('\n');
    return 0;
}

#elif defined(USE_PUBLIC_DOMAIN)
int main(void)
{
    uint32_t l;
    char            buf[100];

    for (;;)
    {
        (void)printf("gimme a number> ");
        if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) == NULL)
            break;
        /* should use strtoul here but some do not have it */
        if (sscanf(buf, "0x%" SCNx32, &l) != 1 &&
            sscanf(buf, "0%"  SCNo32, &l) != 1 &&
            sscanf(buf, "%"   SCNu32, &l) != 1 &&
            sscanf(buf, "%"   SCNx32, &l) != 1)
            (void)printf("that was not a number\n");
        else
            (void)printf("root(%" PRIu32 ") => %" PRIu32 " sqrt(%" PRIu32 ") => %.17g\n",
                          l, isqrt_32(l), l, sqrt((double)l));
    }
    putchar('\n');
    return(0);
}

#else

static const uint32_t tests[] = {
    0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 16, 24, 25, 9999, 10000,
    4294705155, 4294705156, 4294705157, 0xFFFFFFFE, 0xFFFFFFFF,
};

#define DIM(x)  (sizeof(x)/sizeof(*(x)))

int main(void)
{
    int             i;

    for (i = 0; i < DIM(tests); i++)
    {
        uint32_t r = isqrt_32(tests[i]);
        assert(r * r <= tests[i]);
        // assert((r+1) * (r+1) > tests[i]);
        // But avoid overflows!
        assert(tests[i] / (r + 1) < (r + 1));
        printf("ISQRT(%" PRIu32 ") = %" PRId32 "\n", tests[i], r);
    }
    return(0);
}

#endif /* USE_PUBLIC_DOMAIN */
#endif /* TEST */
```

Comment: Yeah, I got that the code can run successfully in the range. I mean it seems that I can't calculate the difference that shows which one is effective. Maybe the standard C library fiction `sqrt()` will work better? And if the answer is true,dose it mean if I want do this operation, write the funtion with myself like that is unecessary and use the standard C library will be better?

Comment: The idea behind the `math_sqrt()` function is that for a 16-bit integer, it will probably be faster than converting from integer to `double`, calling the standard library `sqrt()`, and converting the result back to `int`.  I've not done the benchmark to show that it is correct, though it is plausible.

Comment: Updated with timing information.  On a MacBook Pro with Intel Core i7 chip, using the system library `sqrt()` function is faster than the public domain integer square root calculation.  However, if your CPU doesn't have a hardware SQRT instruction (and a microcontroller may well not have one), then the integer code will probably be a lot faster.

Comment: Thanks for your great answer. I learn more about the square root calculation, how it works and how it effective. I will read your answer attentively and do some test by myself to understand it clearly.